# Going on a tour of the Pentagon as a non-US citizen?

Tags: tours, washington-dc, military

I'm wondering about going on a tour of the Pentagon when I'm in Washington next month.  I'd be interested in knowing what I have to do to apply, and what you get to see on the tour.  Evidently it's free, so if I can go, I'd like to, for sure.

Comment: Currently it says `Foreign Nationals: Changes TBD once we receive more guidance from PFPA.`

Comment: Precisely.  This means that the question cannot be answered until this guidance is available.

Comment: @Karlson ah I'd not seen that part.  I found [a page](http://pentagon.afis.osd.mil/tours.html) that just mentions contacting your embassy.  Hmm. Well I never thought I'd say this, but I just tweeted the Pentagon's twitter account asking :D

Comment: @MarkMayo FWIW, http://pentagontours.osd.mil/ is the canonical URL.

Comment: @choster that's the same site Karlson linked already :) After 9/11 most US bases suspended all visitor rights to foreign nationals except those with business there (contractors, military on assignment). If changes are now TBD my best guess is that's still the status quo at the Pentagon, best thing to do would be I guess to try to contact the responsible office and/or the military attache at your nearest US embassy and inquire about options.

Comment: @jwenting It's the right site, but the wrong location.

Comment: What interesting thing or scene can you find there? I mean is there any old buildings around like historical monuments or Environment? Or something proudly like NASA in Texas to show to the others too?

Comment: Had anyone tried asking pfpa@pfpa.mil this question?

Comment: Did you go in the end?
Are you a UK citizen? (I am)
Was it just a UK passport you needed?
What exactly is the other piece of ID and where do you get it?
:)
Cheers

Comment: I'm surprised they *ever* had tours -- it's a military installation, after all.  I decided they best option would be to build a "Pentagonland" nearby with duplicates of everything that might be of interest to a visitor (minus, obviously, any secret details).  Be sure to include **the button**.  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I went to the building outside, and the memorial garden, which was really nice.

But from there, the Pentagon is like a giant box - you can't see its shape very well. No ID was required, you just walk around.

Never managed to get inside, there's massive security for even walking up to it, and they never replied to me.

However, for the best view, go up to Arlington Cemetery; you get a great view of the Pentagon's shape from there :)

Answer (score 6):

After a quick look at the Pentagon website (http://www.pfpa.mil/visit/access.html), it appears that non US citizens might need to obtain an alien registration card and a social security card, and will need to be escorted during the tour.

However, the language is rather vague and I am not sure what the exact requirements are in order to book a tour.  I recommend calling them (their number is at the bottom of the site near the footer) or emailing them and asking for specifics, as the requirements may vary depending on which country you're from.

EDIT: I just tried to make a tour reservation through the Pentagon's website.  It is possible for non-US citizens to visit, but like all visitors, they will need to provide 2 forms of ID, which in the case of non-US citizens means a visa/passport stamp and proof of country of origin (passport).  One of the forms of ID must contain a photo.

Here is a list of acceptable documents:
http://pentagontours.osd.mil/tour-guidelines.jsp

Here is a snippet from the tour reservation email I received, which confirms that non-US citizens can visit:

"Thank you for your interest in a tour of the Headquarters of the Department of Defense, the Pentagon. Please prepare all of your group's personal information (Ex: Last name, First name, Middle name, City, State, Social Security Number, Date of Birth and **Passport, Visa, Country of origin - for Non-Citizen**) before you request the tour."

Comment: This does not really answer the question. It would if you would perform the recommendations you post (call, e-mail).